# How to create context for the chatbot using twilio

Tags: twilio, chatbot

I am trying to create a bot where when ever someone send a message about a type of food to the bot, then the bot will respond with the location that serves that food. However I am trying to establish context so that the conversation can flow more thoroughly.

I have tried nesting the if statement, and it gets it to display the message, but it would have to rely on the if-statement prior to be true before testing for the ones that comes after.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from intents import fallback_intent, getLocation
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

location_fallback = ['What kind of restaurant are you seeking?', 'What kind? Nearby, Cheap or The best?']
welcome = ['hello', 'what\'s up', 'hey','hi', 'what\'s happening?']
near = ['near', 'nearby']
cheap = ['cheap', 'good for my pockets']
good = ['good', 'top rated']

intro_resp = ['''Hey! Welcome to Crave! This interactive platform connects you to the top foodies in the world! We provide you with the best food places where ever you are. The instructions are simple:
1. Save our number in your Phone as Crave.
2. Text us and tell us what type of food you are craving!

This is from python''', '''
Welcome to Crave! Are you ready to get some food for today?
1. Save our number in your Phone as Crave.
2. Text us and tell us what type of food you are craving!
''']

@app.route('/sms', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sms():
    num = request.form['From']
    msg = request.form['Body'].lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    #welcome intent
    if any(word in msg for word in welcome):
        if any(near_word in msg for near_word in near):
            resp.message('These are the location of places near you!')
            print(str(msg.split()))
            return str(resp)
        elif  any(cheap_word in msg for cheap_word in cheap):
            resp.message('These are the location of places that are low cost to you!')
            return str(resp)
        elif any(good_word in msg for good_word in good):
            resp.message('These are the best places in town!')
            return str(resp)
        else:
            location_fallback[random.randint(0,1)]
        resp.message(intro_resp[random.randint(0, 1)])
        print(str(msg.split()))
        return str(resp)
    else:
        resp.message(fallback_intent())
        print(str(msg))
        return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want the user to say 'hi'' or something related to initiate the bot, then I want the bot to prompt the user to ask what kind of food they would like. Then the bot will ask what parameters for the restaurant they would like(i.e Close, cheap, or good). Then the user will answer accordingly, and then the bot needs to use these parameters to search for the restaurant near them with these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could store this in many places, [in cookies as part of the conversation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-python) with Twilio, in a database where you use the user's number as a key to look up previous messages, or even just in memory.

If you're looking for a more robust way to achieve this, with better natural language processing, have you checked out [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/autopilot)? It stores the context of a conversation for you and is built to collect information before giving a response based on the complete set like you are doing.